# Displaying list properties in a datagrid control

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

I've got a super-simple example form that doesn't seem to be displaying all the data correctly. I'm trying to use the old DataGrid control to display properties in a custom object that are of the `List(Of T)` type. Here's my code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Class o
        Public Property V1 As Integer = 1
        Public Property V2 As Integer = 2
        Public Property V3 As New List(Of Integer)({1, 2, 3})
    End Class

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Dim foo As New o
        Me.DataGrid1.DataSource = New BindingSource(foo, Nothing)
    End Sub

End Class
```

The DataGrid displays as expected - two columns, V1 and V2, with a plus box in the row selector. When I drop that down, I see a link to V3. When I click the link, my header row changes to `o: V1:  1 | V2:  2` with controls to show or hide the parent rows, and an arrow to go back to the full object view. But even though there are three row indicators in the child grid, there are no columns at all. How can I get that child grid to display the values?